# Registry key for reserved Windows keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

In Windows 10, the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut/hotkey opens SnippingTool.exe, located in C:\Windows\System32. Is there a way to remap that shortcut to open a different executable? Ideally would do so without intercepting the keypress with a listener or AutoHotkey.

Can't seem to find a registry value for it.

If I change the name of SnippingTool.exe, pressing the shortcut will generate a window notice that SnippingTool.exe cannot be found. That same error appears if a shortcut named SnippingTool.exe is created and put in C:\Windows\System32 (and the original .exe removed).

Comment: Just overwrite snippingtool.exe with your executable.

Comment: Unfortunately for my needs, I need to change the executable name. I actually want to run SnippingTool.exe, but have it be named something else.